# Check if string has a space

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a string that contains a url. I am trying to check if the url has a space which is invalid.

```
let url = "http://www.example.com/images/pretty pic.png"
```

As you can see in this example, there is a space between pretty and pic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let url = "http://www.example.com/images/pretty pic.png"
let whiteSpace = " "
if let hasWhiteSpace = url.rangeOfString(whiteSpace) {
            print ("has whitespace")
      } else {
            print("no whitespace")
}
```

Comment: Using `containsString(other: String) -> Bool` would make more sense since you are not using the range.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative: check if the set of characters to the string contain a whitespace

```
let url = "http://www.example.com/images/pretty pic.png"
url.characters.contains(" ") // true

let url = "http://www.example.com/images/prettypic.png"
url.characters.contains(" ") // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple indexOf to find the space.

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Comment: Error use of undeclared type s

Answer (score 1):

extension on String which returns bool would be more elegant solution here

```
extension String {
   public var hasWhiteSpace: Bool {
      return self.contains(" ") 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5

```
 var string = "Hi "
    if string.contains(" "){
        print("Has space")
    }else{
        print("Does not have space")
    }
```